# Magento - Manage multilingual images and buttons

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have created a custom template and skin for my multilingual magento website, my skin folder have this tree:

/skin/frontend/mysitename/default

How to use multilingual images and buttons ??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no built-in support for multilingual buttons and images other than to use different designs for different stores (w/ the translated buttons in the skin for them). You could also try to convert the images to use regular text (like the submit buttons in Magento, by default) that can be translated on the fly.

Comment: The default Magento theme package does exactly this; there is `/skin/frontend/default/default`, `/skin/frontend/default/french` and `/skin/frontend/default/german`. Each skin is assigned to corresponding store views.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I have seen the folders in the default theme, but I can't see the french and german skins in the "Custom Design" list in frontend, I have also copied my skin with a new name and it's the same thing, I can't see it in backend ! :(